# Share Photos album on Dropbox

Tags: photos, photos.app

Is there a way to share a Photos album (regular or 'smart') via Dropbox?  I know that I can *copy* the album to DB, but I'd rather create a symlink (or similar) so the photographs aren't duplicated on my HDD.

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried to "Create Alias" for a photo folder, and then put the Alias in Dropbox. Then I went to dropbox.com to see if I could view the folder's contents. The folder is there, but the photos inside could not be viewed. This is the error message I got.

[image: Create Alias Doesn't Work]

When I clicked on "Open" it opened the Dropbox folder on my computer. This would not help me if I were away from my computer and using the web to access my files.

I did come across an app in the Mac App Store called, ["Cloud Storage Helper."](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud-storage-helper-create/id1077981764?mt=12) It bugs me that I don't understand how this app works (and maybe someone else on here does!), but I was able to create links from my computer into my cloud storage and access them online.

[image: Cloud Storage Helper]

Comment: It might use a [symbolic link](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001110610290643), rather than an alias.